# Looping through div rows and collecting the id of the row and column values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have divs acting like a table and I want to loop through each div row in jquery and collect the column values (and also the row id)

How can I do it? code is in this jsffiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/24064/

HTML

```
<div id="tasksTableDiv">
                            <div class="row taskRow" id="1">
                                <div id="description_1"
                                    class="col-sm-2 taskDescriptionCol">Description 1
                 </div>
                 <div id="colour_1"
                                    class="col-sm-2 taskColourCol">Blue
                 </div>
                            </div>
              <div class="row taskRow" id="2">
                                <div id="description_2"
                                    class="col-sm-2 taskDescriptionCol">Description 2
                 </div>
                 <div id="colour_1"
                                    class="col-sm-2 taskColourCol">Red
                 </div>
                            </div>

</div>

<button id="loopButton" type="button"
                            class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Loop</button>
```

JS

```
  $('#loopButton').on('click',function() {
        var ids = [];
        var row = $('.taskRow');
        $.each( row, function() {
         // get the id of each row and get the description and colour
         // ids.push( push the id you got);
                console.log("in loop" + row.html());
            });
  });
```

Comment: Your `$.each()` function isn't doing anything with the elements it's looping over. `row.html()` returns the HTML of the first row, not the current row of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery's [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to loop over the elements and create an array of extracted properties ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wddra37a/)):

```
$('#loopButton').on('click', function() {
  var ids = [];
  var rowsData = $('.taskRow').map(function(index, element) {
    var $fields = $(this).find('div');
    return {
      id: this.id,
      label: $fields.eq(0).text().trim(),
      description: $fields.eq(1).text().trim()
    };
  }).toArray();

  console.log(rowsData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with plain javascript

```
  var loopButton = document.getElementById("loopButton");

  loopButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    let ids = [];
    var rows = document.getElementsByClassName("taskRow");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(rows, function(r){
        ids.push(r.id)
      console.log(r.children[0].innerHTML)
    })
    console.log(ids);
  });
```